# Firefox add-on review with external libs

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, mozilla

I would like to submit an add-on into FF AMO. My project includes some external libs and after uploading my xpi to the store I got the message that I need to fix the following issues to have the faster automated review and signing:

- Markup should not be passed to `innerHTML` dynamically.
- Access to the `Function` global

It finds this issues for example inside the following files:

- data/Pages/bower_components/jquery/src/core.js
- data/Pages/lib/underscore.js

What could I do to ignore files from review process? 
Is there any options to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The feedback returned is not regarding the external libs it seems. External libs are totally fine, you just need to use the exact official copy, don't modify it. I use angular in a lot of my stuff. Just reply to the email from the reviewer and explain to them that the innerHTML and Function global are within the jQuery library. Also do not import jquery into the global nsIDOMwindow scope, only use them in your content scripts, or if you wrote an html page for your addon you can use it there. Otherwise you'll pollute the Firefox function scope and break things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of work our automatic review was successful.

In this case with the third party libs the problems and the solutions were the followings:

- Third party source codes installed with bower and stored in bower_components can be detected as third party libs and if they are in the FF review system already - like angular, jquery - they will be ignored. **Everything is OK.**
- Using third-party libs added to the project in a custom way - copying a minified file into a custom named folder will be detected as own code and will be reviewed. **Do not use them like that way. Install them with bower instead.**
- But as you could see it was problem with a bower installed file as well in the Question: data/Pages/bower_components/jquery/src/core.js. Before creating the xpi that you will upload it is recommended to clear (better in an automatized way e.g. with gulp) the bower_compontents as well from the source codes. **Keep only the dist file or files of bower_components.**